# Forms authentication for www and without www

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, forms-authentication

This is part of my config file

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" enableCrossAppRedirects="true"
          name="authtoken" domain="localsite.com" />
</authentication>
```

This is my method for authentication

```
public void Authenticate(string token, int userId)
{
    var userData = new FormTicketUserData() {UserId = userId};
    var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, token, DateTime.Now, DateTime.MaxValue,  
                                               false, userData.ToString());
    var encryptString = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
    var authCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptString);
    authCookie.Path = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath;
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Remove(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);
    HttpContext.Current.User = new MyFormsPrincipal(new FormsIdentity(ticket), userId);
    UserContext.Refresh();
}
```

When I Authenticate on www.localsite.com,I don't Authenticate on localsite.com and vice versa.
When I Authenticate on www.localsite.com,I need be Authenticate on localsite.com too.
How can I do this.

Comment: might i suggest having a canonical domain name?

Answer (score 0):

This solved problem

```
authCookie.Domain = "localsite.com";
```